# The pural opi for opus is a joke, right?

Tags: irregular-plurals

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/opus attests that some people in the classical music world use "opi" as a plural for "opus."  I think this is just a joke, giving a pseudo-learned false-Latin form for the plural.  But I want to make sure.

Can anyone here who is familiar with the usage at first hand tell me whether it is generally meant as a joke?

Comment: From the article: "The most common plural of opus in English is opuses. Some people use the Latin plural, opera. Opi is fairly common in the field of classical music, though mostly in informal contexts." So "informal" yes, but "joke" is up to interpretation. The plural of opus is also opera (e.g. https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/opus.html)

Comment: The Wiktionary page for [magnum opus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/magnum_opus) cites **three** plural forms: magna opera, magnum opuses and magnum opi.

Comment: @WeatherVane  Yes, the first is correct Latin, the second follows English rules, and I hope the third is intended as humorous.

Comment: Latin: opus:opera http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:opus opi is not the nominative plural of opus.

Comment: Google Ngrams for 'opi' and 'opuses' seem to show that the former outperforms the latter. I haven't been able to come up with a suitable filter to ensure the plural 'opera' (one that doesn't lead to flatlines). But **usage** rather than individual preference drives acceptability, and appeals to traditional rules are themselves selective. Why not a 'model plurals on look-alike even if false Latin forms' rule?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Certainly, while I would prefer that opi be a joke, what matters is whether it is *used* as a joke.

Comment: Yes, it is an in-joke, which I can confirm as a former instrument player in orchestras. It's not confined to the arts world though. I have heard people jokingly pluralise other words with -i that don't even end with -us. It's probably more common among those who learnt Latin at school (as I did). Allied is the use of 'platypi' colloquially but in this case the word platypus is made up from Greek.

Comment: It's based on a parallel with cactus->cacti, octopus->octopi (although octopuses is more common now), virus->viri (or virii).

Comment: See https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wc/between-us-and-i-getting-stuck-on-plurals/

Comment: @Barmar, please, not the octopus thing again (that's come up here before, several times)

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you make that an answer?  It does answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is an in-joke, which I can confirm as a former instrument player in orchestras.

It's not confined to the arts world though. I have heard people jokingly pluralise other words with -i that don't even end with -us. It's probably more common among those who learnt Latin at school (as I did).

Allied is the use of 'platypi' colloquially but in this case the word platypus was neologized from Greek roots.

Comment: Are you sure that *platypi* is really 'allied' (i.e. that it is a joke like *opi*, rather than a genuine hypercorrection)?

Answer (score 1):

(Dredging up my schoolgirl Latin) Many Latin nouns ending in -us are second declension, with plural -i. However, *opus* happens to be a third declension noun, and its plural is *opera.* See latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:opus

As others have pointed out, *octopus* and *platypus* are derived from Greek, so they don't have plurals in -i either.

Comment: How does this answer the question? 'Octopi' is a licensed English word, no matter how unimpressive its pedigree. The 'correctly formed' 'octopodes' is nigh on  unidiomatic. Sometimes apparent rules are followed, sometimes they aren't. OP is asking about a particular candidate word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Since Latin is less widely taught nowadays, I was just clarifying why it is that not all words ending in -us have -i plurals.

Comment: That would of course be useful. In a comment, as (1) it doesn't address the situation with OP's 'opi' directly, and (2) can't be taken as giving rise to a strict rule, as the bastardised 'octopi' is nevertheless seen as acceptable by some.

Comment: The OP already knows that *opi* is incorrect. The question is whether 'in the classical music world' it is used jokingly (i.e. in awareness of its being incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

Opi is a common joke amongst the Japanese speaking as well. "Opus" is used to name a specific type of Electrical control in my industry, but a few of our engineers know the plural form "Opi" means "Breasts" or "Boobs" in Japanese!!!!